# Clearing createGraphics() canvas from p5js renderer

Tags: processing, p5.js

p5js has a clear() function which clears everything from the screen. I want to keep the canvas created by createCanvas() but clear the createGraphics() one only. How can I do this ?

```
//something like this
var canvas2;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  canvas2 = createGraphics(400,400);
  canvas2.clear()
  noLoop()
}

function draw() {
  fill(255,0,0)
  rect(60,60,40,40)
  canvas2.fill(20,44,240);
  canvas2.rect(20,20,40,40);
  image(canvas2,0,0)
}

function mousePressed() {
  //something which clears the createGraphics() canvas only and keeps the createCanvas() one
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] showing what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the content of a graphics object using its `clear()` function. Here's an example:

```js
var canvas2;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  canvas2 = createGraphics(400,400);
  canvas2.fill(20,44,240);
  canvas2.rect(20,20,40,40);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);

  fill(255,0,0)
  rect(60,60,40,40)

  image(canvas2,0,0)
}

function mousePressed() {
  canvas2.clear();
}
```

I moved the `canvas2.rect(20, 20, 40, 40)` call to be inside the `setup()` function, because otherwise you're redrawing to the canvas even after you clear it. I also removed your `noLoop()` call so that you could see the result of clearing the canvas.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do this with the noLoop(), the way I was implementing it ? This was just a small part of what I was trying to do, and I need the noLoop() there.

Comment: @Sandler2k1 You can move the call to `noLoop()` to the end of your `draw()` function, and then call `loop()` from `mousePressed()`. That way when you click the mouse, you trigger another frame, but you don't keep drawing additional frames.

Comment: @Sandler2k1 You can use the [redraw()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/redraw) method to call `draw()` without looping

Comment: @Dietrich I hadn't seen that function before, that's a cool tip!